# eliminating blank pages in SSRS 2005 pdf-generated report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that generates a number of blank pages at the start when rendering in pdf format.  The first page has a table with conditional visibility on it, so that's likely contributing, but it's *only* one page, and there are sometimes 3-4 blank pages at the start, before the meat of the report begins.  This only happens when rendering as a pdf, and the report's width is 8.25 inches, so I don't believe it's a case of horizontal wrapping.

I believe there's an option in SSRS 2008 that consolidates blank pages; is there anything similar in SSRS 2005 that I can try?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue awhile back but can't remeber how i fixed it. I think I had to play with some of the page size properties and perhaps check the page break options on all of your report elements

Answer (score 3):

hi there:
  Check the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace property on Report if you are using SSRS2008. Turn it to true. 
  Or make sure your body size is set up correctly

Comment: Where is this property located?

Answer (score 1):

Sizing of controls versus size of the body of the report is very often the issue here.

One quick way in SSRS 2005 is to blank the Body's size properties.

Right click on report surface, select Properties to get Body selected in the Property window. Then find the Size section and delete everything in. Save and try exporting to PDF.

When you do this, SSRS recalculates the Body size based on your controls in the report.

There is lots more excellent information [here](http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/03/18/the-case-of-the-extra-page/comment-page-1/#comment-75590) regarding other options

Answer (score 0):

Get Rid of the Extra blank page from SSRS 2005, exporting to PDF, Word or Excel, using Report Manager, but have the table footer in the last page

Move all textbox’s, Lines, Images, tables and etc…  inside a List > Then Select List > Properties Page > General Tab > Select > Drop Down For the “Data set name:” select the main Dataset for the table here > Select:  “Edit details group” > General Tab > “Group on:” enter =”” >  Select checkbox for “Page break at start” > Ok > Select the list that you just created > Move to the top left hand corner of your body, also make sure to select the list then (ctrl + up) and (ctrl + left), to position it flush against these sides > After this is done > Select the table1 > Properties Page > Groups Tab > Select > Add > in the General tab > Group on: Expression: enter: =Int((RowNumber("table1")-1)/ Parameters!Rows_Per_Page.Value ) > “Page break at end” should be selected, everthing else deselected > Make sure if you have other table grouping in the “Group list:” the one you just created should be the first one on the list. > Report > Report Parameters > Add > Rows_Per_Page > Unselect everthing except, Internal > “Default values:” > Non-queried =300000 > OK > Make sure the Right side of the body is flush against the right side of the List and the bottom of the body is flush against the bottom of the list > preview the report in report manager > export to PDF, Word or Excel and there will be no blank pages, but have the table footer on the last page.

Comment: Also, under the Table Properties > General tab > under Header/footer: make sure the "Repeat header rows on each page" is unchecked

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS 2005 try setting the CanGrow property of every textbox on your page to False. Helped my report. (My report has kind of free letter layout.)